# how to disable day in Datebox using Zk

Tags: java, zk

I have changed color on selected date

You can find [zk fiddle here](http://zkfiddle.org/sample/2dih3qq/1-how-to-disable-day-in-Datebox-in-Zk.)

Now i want disable day. It should not be clickble.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently the enable/disable of a date is rely on its css class, you can add Datebox.getZclass()+'-disd' to disable it at client side, please refer to the sample at zkfiddle:

[How to disable day in Datebox in Zk](http://zkfiddle.org/sample/2dih3qq/3-how-to-disable-day-in-Datebox-in-Zk)

This way you can save some au request, but still need to add server side validation properly for set date by java API.

Comment: Hi benbai, How can i pass date array value to javascript inside aftercompose

Comment: i have try http://zkfiddle.org/sample/15d409/23-Disable-Datebox way but after click the calendar it's changes

Comment: please look my question on stackoverflow http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16102009/how-to-pass-array-value-to-javascript-in-zk

Comment: hi benbai, how to select whole week in calendar. Please look this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16190586/how-to-selected-week-in-calendar-in-zk

Answer (score 1):

The [datebox constraint](http://books.zkoss.org/wiki/ZK_Component_Reference/Input/Datebox#Constraint) is based on [`SimpleDateConstraint`](http://www.zkoss.org/javadoc/latest/zk/org/zkoss/zul/SimpleDateConstraint.html) which only supports a **date range** unfortunately: you cannot black out specific dates in this manner.

I believe the correct way to do this is not to make the date un-selectable in the UI, per se, but to ignore the date when it is selected. Combining this with visually blacking out the date like you've done already, and you'll get the effect you are looking for.

To do this *on the Java side* you can implement a custom [`ClientConstraint`](http://www.zkoss.org/javadoc/latest/zk/org/zkoss/zul/ClientConstraint.html). This will actually validate your input values in JavaScript, as opposed to the normal server-side [`Constraint`](http://www.zkoss.org/javadoc/latest/zk/org/zkoss/zul/Constraint.html).

You can, of course, dig into the [Datebox JavaScript widget](http://www.zkoss.org/javadoc/latest/jsdoc/zul/db/Datebox.html) itself but I tend to shy away from that approach when possible. In fact, you'll see the [`datebox.validate_`](http://www.zkoss.org/javadoc/latest/jsdoc/zul/inp/InputWidget.html#validate_%28java.lang.Object%29) function bridges this gap for you by integrating the aforementioned `ClientConstraint`.