# How to pass array value to javascript in zk

Tags: javascript, zk

As per my requirement i have to pass date array to javascript for color change calendar day .

but i have done http://zkfiddle.org/sample/15d409/23-Disable-Datebox way but it's change value after click on calendar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because Clients.evalJavaScript will eval jsCommand AFTER all other js function of widgets are done in that case, since the command for render widget (renderProperties) will be called before doAfterCompose.

What you need is setWidgetOverride, use it to override redraw of calendar widget, please refer to the updated sample.

[Calendar coloring sample](http://zkfiddle.org/sample/15d409/24-Disable-Datebox)

Comment: when i use setWidgetOverride it changes whole application calendar. can i use a specific calendar. same page i use 3-4 calendar it changes whole calendar.

Comment: sure, you can assign a sclass to that specific calendar, and detect it as if (jq(wgt.%n()).hasClass('the-class-you-assigned')) {do overridden tasks}

Comment: please refer to the similar case

http://ben-bai.blogspot.tw/2013/01/zk-datebox-customize-datebox-as.html

and

http://ben-bai.blogspot.tw/2013/01/extending-and-customizing-zk-component.html