# How to selected week in calendar in zk

Tags: java, javascript, zk

how to selected whole week in calendar on onclick on `Calendar` component. Just like this image.

[image]

Comment: Maybe this [link](http://www.zkoss.org/zkdemo/application/zk_calendar) helpful for you

Comment: @Sandy here he is asking if we can select a whole week in Calendar components.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can override _markCal js function (used to mark the selected date) to style whole row and fire event to server to update selected dates, please refer to:

[online demo](http://screencast.com/t/N35NM2T98yY)

[calendar_as_week_picker.zul](https://github.com/benbai123/ZK_Practice/blob/master/Components/projects/Components_Practice/WebContent/calendar_as_week_picker.zul)

[WeekPicker.java](https://github.com/benbai123/ZK_Practice/blob/master/Components/projects/Components_Practice/src/test/custom/component/WeekPicker.java)

and

[related article at my blog](http://ben-bai.blogspot.tw/2013/04/zk-calendar-as-week-picker.html)

Answer (score 0):

For the version 7 of zk use:

```
<zk xmlns:w="client">
<style>
    .custom-selected-node {
        background-color: #99FF99 !important;
    }
</style>
<vlayout>
    <label value="selected dates" />
    <textbox rows="7" id="tbx" width="300px" />
</vlayout>
<calendar id="cal" use="test.custom.component.WeekPicker">
    <attribute w:name="_markCal"><![CDATA[
        function (opts) {
            // clear old custom-selected-node
            jq('.custom-selected-node').each(function () {
                jq(this).removeClass('custom-selected-node');
            });
            this.$_markCal(opts);
            if (this._view == 'day') {
                // target: current focused date (td)
                // parent: tr
                var target = jq('.z-calendar-selected')[0],
                    parent = target.parentNode,
                    node = parent.firstChild,
                    beforeCnt = 0,
                    found;
                // loop through each td
                while (node) {
                    // add selected style
                    jq(node).addClass('custom-selected-node');
                    if (node == target) {
                        found = true;
                    } else if (!found) {
                        // count nodes before target
                        beforeCnt++;
                    }
                    node = node.nextSibling;
                }
                // fire event to server
                this.fire('onCustomSelect', {bcnt: beforeCnt});
            }
        }
    ]]></attribute>
    <attribute name="onCustomSelect"><![CDATA[
        List dates = self.getSelectedDates();
        java.text.SimpleDateFormat sdf = new java.text.SimpleDateFormat("dd / MM / yyyy");
        String value = "";
        for (int i = 0; i < dates.size(); i++) {
            value = value + sdf.format((Date)dates.get(i)) + "\n";
        }
        tbx.setValue(value);
    ]]></attribute>
</calendar>
```